# iOS stack trace not accurate

Tags: ios, stack-trace

I am developing a iOS application and experiencing a crash. I cannot debug it because I need a serial communication implement that takes the place of the Apple connector.
I have managed to generate a stack trace at the instance of failure:

```
    0 - 0   Flashtool_iPad                      0x0003d8c1 SignalHandler + 152
   1 - 1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3c0fee93 _sigtramp + 42
   2 - 2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3c12283d __sfvwrite + 352
   3 - 3   Flashtool_iPad                      0x00041811 -[ProgrammingLogic execute_programming_procedure] + 716
   4 - 4   Flashtool_iPad                      0x0003e86f __52-[ProgramViewController programController:forEvent:]_block_invoke + 54
   5 - 5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3c09811f <redacted> + 10
   6 - 6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3c09becf <redacted> + 142
   7 - 7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3c09bdc1 <redacted> + 40
   8 - 8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3c09c91d <redacted> + 184
   9 - 9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3c09cac1 <redacted> + 84
  10 - 10  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3c0cca11 <redacted> + 360
  11 - 11  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3c0cc8a4 start_wqthread + 8
```

but unfortunately, the forth line indicating where the actual failure happened (`3 - 3   Flashtool_iPad                      0x00041811 -[ProgrammingLogic execute_programming_procedure] + 716`) points to a comment in the objective C code...this statement: `4 - 4   Flashtool_iPad                      0x0003e86f __52-[ProgramViewController programController:forEvent:]_block_invoke + 54` actually appears on line 48 of the source - not 54 !
So where does the offset come from?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The offsets are not indicating lines, but bytes from the beginning of the function in the machine code.

Comment: I see, then I was misled by some online source. I tried to locate my function in the machine code using a memory window to determine which instruction causes the trouble but Xcode displays nothing but 0s. There is no traditional ".map" file generated indicating where everything is placed (I guess that is intentional!). Can you advise me how to find the abusing instruction without a debugger? Thanks!

Comment: @TamirMichael If you compile your code using the `-g` flag (preferably combined with `-O0`), then GDB will happily show the line number when you request a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. I am not a iOS developer (as you can determine...). I am coming from the world of embedded development - sorry for asking the obvious! I tried this using LLVM GCC 4.2 but it will not build. Is there a way to achieve this using the default compiler?

Comment: @TamirMichael Clang has all the options GCC has.

Comment: As far as I can determine, the code is built using the suggested flags - I filled in "-g -O0" at "Other C flags" in the project settings (is this the way to do it?). I see no difference in my stack trace (it is loaded during startup, written in the signal handler) - is there a way to view the machine code itself or is that not an option?

Comment: @TamirMichael Yes, that's what you should do. I don't know what the problem could be... You can view the machine code by typing "disasm" in the debugger.

Comment: In Xcode 4.2, you can see the assembly or disassembly for a file by:

Showing the assistant editor (command+option+Enter is the default shortcut).
In the JumpBar, select the tuxedo icon and select "Assembly" or "Disassembly" from the drop-down list.
You can view the Assembly for a file whether or not you're running the application. Disassembly is only available when the application is running and being debugged.

But of course, this cannot be done for an arbitrary file - only the one where the application is stopped. _sniff_ ... !